# M2E in Eclipse gives maven-compiler-plugin errors, but Maven installation is fine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've installed Maven 3.3.9 and I'm running Eclipse Mars 2 with JDK 1.8.0_65.

I've tried to create a Maven Project, yet it always returns four errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5 -> org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4 -> log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12: ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.12 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.   pom.xml /PluginBasedPasswords   line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

I get a similar error to the one above but for *plugin execution default-testCompile*

The other two (one for default-compile and the other for default-testCompile) have a structure like this:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)    pom.xml /PluginBasedPasswords   line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

The project creation wizard shows me a similar version:

[image: Import Maven Projects GUI showing the errors I'm receiving.]

I've followed several tutorials for installing Maven and setting my environment variables so I doubt it is them (if needed: PATH: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73;`, M2_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9` and JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`)

My Maven installation seems to be functional because running `mvn -version` returns:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:4
7+00:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

I've also updated my M2E plugin via the Esclipse Marketplace so I truly have no idea what's going wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have the most up-to-date version of M2E. So to solve this, I uninstalled all versions of M2E that came with Eclipse. Then I followed the instructions on http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

However, I had previously just added that exact URL to Eclipse's Install New Software dialogue. What you have to do instead is click the link to *Show Directory Contents* and select the version of M2E you wish to use. In this case, it was 1.6. Then you select the most recent sub-version.

Once done, copy the new URL from your browser and add it to the install software dialogue. The URL in this case was http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.6/1.6.2.20150902-0002/?d. Once this was done, everything suddenly worked!

Hope that has helped someone in my situation.